# TTS: How do I detect when voice is done being spoken while keeping the connection open?

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I have a mobile web app where there are multiple spoken prompts, each one followed by the user speaking a response. The user can press a button to start the process but then must be able to answer the prompts hands free.

In order for the audio to not be blocked on Safari and Chrome mobile the synthesizer must be started with a user interaction like a button press. This works initially. If I could keep the synthesizer object open I could continue to use it from this one button press without needing the user to press another button.

However, I also need to detect when the spoken voice is complete:

```js
    const player = new SpeechSDK.SpeakerAudioDestination();
    player.onAudioEnd = () => {
      resolve();
    };
```

It looks like `onAudioEnd` only fires when the synthesizer is closed after speaking:

```js
 synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(`...`,
      (result) => {
        if (result) {
          synthesizer.close();  // <---- Without this onAudioEnd never fires
          return result.audioData;
        }
        return undefined;
      });
```

But when I close the synthesizer, then mobile browsers require another button press before I can open a new synthesizer.

Is there any way I can get around this?